# appcelerator titanium build so slow

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using appcelerator titanium to develop apps.

Recently, I found it took so long(1 min at least, 5 mins or more at most) when I ran the build with "appc ti build -p ios -T device".

How to make it fast?

My computer is iMac with I5 CPU and 8GB RAM.

Comment: On the hardware side: a SSD speeds up compiling significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Appc run -p ios -T device --liveview

When liveview is activated the app get's updated quick
When file changes in the project were detected 
Titanium reload the new app very fast.

Liveview don't reload new files
And updated/added modules.